# NavMeshAgent in unity not working

Tags: unity, navmesh

I am making a game in unity and it is throwing the error "Failed to create agent because there is no valid NavMesh" and i don't know what the problem is.

[image: Setup Picture]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMotion : MonoBehaviour {
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public GameObject otwt;

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
    void Update () {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(270, 0, 0);
        agent.SetDestination(otwt.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [bake a navmesh](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/navigation/navmesh-baking) first.